# java loop stuck at first output

Tags: java, loops

**Complete overhaul**: I revised the whole source and found a solution; this question is no longer applicable.

Here's the loop:

```
       for(String x : options){
            while(!(x.equals(input))){
                pl("\t Please enter a valid option!");
                input = TextIO.getlnWord().toUpperCase();
            }
        }
```

**The scenario**: I have an array of Strings named `options` full of values. I would like to validate that the user has entered a valid String from options. If so, move on.

**The problem**: It's not validating, and the loop keeps running.

Do I need to create/override a `contains()` method, and then use the validation from that to move on? If anyone could explain the problem and offer input on the best or most accepted way to do something like this, please feel free.

Comment: input.equals(null) this seems crazy if input is null you will never enter and if you enter it will throw nullpointer. Hence input can not become null with this  call  input = TextIO.getlnWord().toUpperCase(); since you get the nullpointer when thrying to do .toUpperCase();

Comment: I think TextIO covered that exception; I just tried it again and it didn't output the `if` statement. I will have to deal with that as well. Any other comments on how to deal with this validation?

Comment: if (TextIO.getlnWord()==null) ... but I can't really understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: if input = null and you do input.equals(null) you should get NullPointerException. No?

Comment: What is `TextIO.getlnWord()`, and what is `input` initialized as (before the loop)? Typical option parsing will iterate the input, check against known options, and set the option value. You could use a HashTable with your `options` as keys, for instance, and check if they are all set by looking at `HashTable.values()`..

Comment: I've removed that section because if it were null it would return false anyway to the `while` statement. The loop still will not validate.

Comment: I would suggest that you re-think what you trying to do... also the while statement seems strange, TextIO.getlnWord() will change while your in while... doubt it... remove the while aswell

Comment: update the text of your question too please.

Comment: @PhilC. correct me if I am wrong. You have a list of options, and you would like to take input from user and then check if the input is a valid option form the options or not? If not ask again, if yes move on? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and I'm still working on it actually. I had to take time off yesterday cause it was bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

In an if / else statement, one of the blocks is always going to run.

```
if(input.equals(null)){
    pl("\t Please enter an option!");
} else {
    pl("\t Please enter a valid option!");
}
```

That means when you have this if statement it is always going to run one the else block when it doesn't run the if statement. If you don't want the if statement to act like this you should replace else with else if:

```
if(input.equals(null)){
    pl("\t Please enter an option!");
} else if (/* Validation logic goes here */) {
    pl("\t Please enter a valid option!");
}
```

EDIT: Wait was the code in the question just edited or have i lost my mind?

Comment: I removed the `input.equals(null)` exceptions, check the edits. BUT @Xyexs I tried this and it validated. I can't believe I overlooked that simple fact about `if/else`s

Comment: But now I have to find another way around it